# Secondary navigation menu on one page

Tags: php, menus, templates

I have this wp designed link where i have Home, Services, About, and Contact. Under Services i have separate menus like webdesign, webdevelopment, seo, maintenance and so on..

I have created the secondary nagivations in the menu page (Admin > Appearance > Menu). I have this code.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( 
    array( 
        'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu', 
        'menu_class'     => 'secondary', 'fallback_cb' => ''
        )); 
?>
```

Where should I place this, because the `pages.php` is for all the pages.

Comment: So you have one primary menu and one secondary, and you want secondary menu to be on one specific page. Am I getting this correct?

Comment: @AniruddhaGawade Yes, The secondary menu displays below the cover image. Iam using Bootstrap framework and the navbar stays on top and on the service page - below the cover image the secondary menu displays.

Comment: In that case you'll have to create a separate template for that page.

Comment: you mean one page like `pages.php` but this one is to target the service page alone.

Comment: Yes. page-{page-slug}.php. This way you'll get code from this file to your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this menu on one page only, let's say About Us (slug: `about-us`), you can easily add a [conditional](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) like this in `pages.php` at the place where you want the menu to appear:

```
if (is_page('about-us')) {
  wp_nav_menu( 
    array( 
        'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu', 
        'menu_class'     => 'secondary', 'fallback_cb' => ''
        )); 
  }
```

Remember that if you have a third party theme, you should build a child theme for this page, because else your adaptation will be lost when the theme is updated.

Comment: Thank you!. There is no third party theme. New theme is created with  Bootstrap framework as a base.

Comment: This is what i added in the function - `add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_menus' ); function my_custom_menus() { register_nav_menus( array( 'secondary-menu' => __( 'Services Page')));}` and this is what i added in the page.php - `<?php if (is_page('home')) {wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'Service Page', 'menu_class'     => 'secondary', 'fallback_cb' => ''));}?>`. I want to test it on the homepage first so i gave the slug as `home`. I cannot see anything. What iam missing. The menu name `wp-secondary-menu` in the appearance.

Comment: It's working now. The menu went behind the navbar.